# If the `which` is used correctly?

Tags: sentence-construction, relative-pronouns

I wrote the following sentences in my paper:

> It's only after 1998, the practical realization of **the tiny devices** called "Motes"  by the Smart Dust project at the University of California at
>   Berkeley, **which** could compute and communicate wirelessly, and to **which** sensors could be connected, that  has since triggered a new wave of research in WSN, not only in theoretic development, but also in engineering practice.

My question is that, I want the **which** refers to **the tiny devices**, I don't know if I use it correctly.

Comment: Where is the verb for the subject, **the practical realization**?

Comment: In fact, it's **triggered**

Comment: It is not. The subject of **has trigered** is **that**. You don't need to write in a long sentence in which you get lost.

Comment: I think the _which_ is fine.  The rest of the sentence is very hard to understand.  You should probably break it into smaller sentences, like JayHook suggests.

Answer (score 1):

> It's only after 1998, the practical realization of the tiny devices
>   called "Motes" by the Smart Dust project at the University of
>   California at Berkeley, which could compute and communicate
>   wirelessly, and to which sensors could be connected, that has since
>   triggered a new wave of research in WSN, not only in theoretic
>   development, but also in engineering practice.

This sentence is ungrammatical with respect to its use of time-phrases.

> It's only after 1998...that has since triggered...

We can divide the sentence into several sentences with no loss of clarity. By "practical realization" I assume you mean something like the successful fabrication|demonstration.

**In 1998, the Smart Dust project at the University of California at Berkeley successfully demonstrated the "Mote", a tiny computing device to which sensors could be attached; it was also capable of communicating wirelessly. The practical realization of these minuscule devices triggered a new wave of Wireless Sensor Network research and had a profound effect on both engineering theory and practice.**

Answer (score 0):

I think you should again insert the word for better clarity .Try this .....University of California at Berkeley, devices which .....

Comment: Written like this, I can't understand what you are trying to say. Please elaborate a bit, perhaps suggesting a longer sentence? Also, you could mark the quote with a preceding ">" for better readability (or use the controls above the text window).

Comment: As a native speaker, I understand what you are suggesting, and agree that it could be a good approach.  To a non-native speaker, it would be helpful if you followed Stephie's formatting suggestion, supply more of the sample sentence, with emphasis on the change, and explain why it helps.  I am not voting to close, because I believe you can improve this into a good answer.  :-)